# TableView is reloaded when you navigate away then back

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I've built an iOS 7 app using storyboards. Within my offersViewController I have a UIView and a UITableView. The UIView acts as a subview that displays a loading message while my feed is been parsed. Once complete the subview is removed and my parsed data is presented in my UITableView.

```
@interface OffersViewController ()

@end

@implementation OffersViewController
@synthesize loadingView;

MoreCobaltOffers *currentFeed;
AppDelegate *appDelegate;

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tableView addSubview:loadingView];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navigation"]];

    CustomStringParser *customStringParser = [[CustomStringParser alloc] init];

    // Download and parse XML data
    RXMLElement *rxml = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myrssfeed.com"]]];

    // Create an reference to AppDelegate
    appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    // Create an array to store each feed
    appDelegate.offersFeeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Loop Through XML Data
    [rxml iterate:@"channel" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *supportElement) {

        [supportElement iterate:@"item" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *repElement) {

            // Assign element to string
            NSString *title = [repElement child:@"title"].text;
            NSString *subtitle = [repElement child:@"tagline"].text;
            NSString *description = [repElement child:@"description"].text;
            NSString *imageurl = [repElement child:@"image"].text;
            NSString *address = [repElement child:@"address"].text;

            // Assign element value to MoreCobalt.h propertys
            currentFeed = [MoreCobaltOffers alloc];
            currentFeed.title = title;
            currentFeed.imageurl = imageurl;
            currentFeed.addressline = address;

            // DESCRIPTION FORMATTING
            description = [customStringParser parseHTML:description];
            description = [customStringParser parseLinesMultiple:description];
            description = [customStringParser removeSocialSignifiers:description];
            description = [customStringParser appendTermsOfUse:description];
            currentFeed.description = description;

            // SUBTITLE FORMATTING
            subtitle = [customStringParser parseHTML:subtitle];
            subtitle = [customStringParser parseLinesSingle:subtitle];
            subtitle = [customStringParser removeSocialSignifiers:subtitle];
            currentFeed.subtitle = subtitle;

            // Add a new object to the feeds array
            [[appDelegate offersFeeds] addObject:currentFeed];
        }];

        //Remove the loading screen
        [loadingView removeFromSuperview];

        //Show table data, if this is not here the table is empty.
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
}
```

When I run the app the loading screen appears and then the table is displayed with data. If I navigate away from this view controller to another tab and then navigate back the table will flash. Not very good user experience.

The line of code responsible is `[self.tableView reloadData];`. I need this in or table becomes empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing. But you don't necessarily need that code in `viewDidAppear:`...

Comment: Surely it should be done in -viewDidLoad instead? The tableView is being reloaded whenever the view appears, rather than just once i.e. in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: You are reloading tableView in viewDidAppear... and it means it will reload data every time when view appears... Now if you need to reload tableView every time when your view is going to appear take this code inside ViewWillAppear. If you want just to load data once. take this code to viewDidLoad...

Comment: If I put the code inside of viewDidLoad the "loading" UIView does not show anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewWillAppear is called any time the view appears. In order for the table not to reload each time, move the code inside viewDidAppear.

For showing the loading view only one time move the parsing to another method like:

```
- (void)parseFeed {
    [self.loadingIndicator startAnimating];
    self.loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navigation"]];

    CustomStringParser *customStringParser = [[CustomStringParser alloc] init];

    // Download and parse XML data
    RXMLElement *rxml = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.morecobalt.co.uk/rss/?t=offers"]]];

    // Create an reference to AppDelegate
    appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    // Create an array to store each feed
    appDelegate.offersFeeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Loop Through XML Data
    [rxml iterate:@"channel" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *supportElement) {

        [supportElement iterate:@"item" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *repElement) {

            // Assign element to string
            NSString *title = [repElement child:@"title"].text;
            NSString *subtitle = [repElement child:@"tagline"].text;
            NSString *description = [repElement child:@"description"].text;
            NSString *imageurl = [repElement child:@"image"].text;
            NSString *address = [repElement child:@"address"].text;

            // Assign element value to MoreCobalt.h propertys
            currentFeed = [MoreCobaltOffers alloc];
            currentFeed.title = title;
            currentFeed.imageurl = imageurl;
            currentFeed.addressline = address;

            // DESCRIPTION FORMATTING
            description = [customStringParser parseHTML:description];
            description = [customStringParser parseLinesMultiple:description];
            description = [customStringParser removeSocialSignifiers:description];
            description = [customStringParser appendTermsOfUse:description];
            currentFeed.description = description;

            // SUBTITLE FORMATTING
            subtitle = [customStringParser parseHTML:subtitle];
            subtitle = [customStringParser parseLinesSingle:subtitle];
            subtitle = [customStringParser removeSocialSignifiers:subtitle];
            currentFeed.subtitle = subtitle;

            // Add a new object to the feeds array
            [[appDelegate offersFeeds] addObject:currentFeed];
        }];
        [loadingView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
    [loadingView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
    isFirstLoad = NO;
}
```

Declare a BOOL to check if it is first load and do this check:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (isFirstLoad){
    [self parseFeed];
    }
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this way as well. The "loadin"g UIView does not appear anymore.

Comment: It does not appear because the data are already loaded. Only the first time a view is loaded does the code in ViewDidLoad run. All the other times (navigate back to that view etc) viewDidLoad is not called.

Comment: So whats the fix here?

Comment: Why would you like the loader to show app everytime you enter the view even the data are already loaded?

Comment: Your right the behaviour is incorrect. It should be inside of viewDidLoad... however if I do put it there I don't get the loading screen anymore.

Comment: There is no need to see the loading screen when the data are already loaded. You just want to see the loading screen on the first time while data are downloading.

Comment: You just use the code from my answer. close completely the app, run it again and you will see the loading view the first time you enter that view. Of course you have to remove the viewWillAppear method.

Comment: Thanks again Nikos, I've tried the above code and you don't get to see the loading screen. When the app opens it sticks on the launch screen until the xml data is parsed then the table is shown. Could it be something to do the blocks?

Comment: No, code in viewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear is executed in exactly the same way with the only difference that viewDidLoad is executed only in the first time. So if you saw the loading view with your code and you don't see it with mine, it is definitely a strange issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40379/discussion-between-user2920762-and-nikos-m)

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I wanted the view to do. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Few things worth nothing:

1. You should extract all of that code for the parsing of your XML into another class. You should not be parsing data from XML inside of a view controller.
2. Right now you're running your network calls and parsing the XML data every time the view appears. What you might consider is only doing it when the view loads, thus running your code in `viewDidLoad`
3. Whenever you end up moving the code you might consider having a temporary local array and filling that with the XML return values, then using `isEqualToArray` to compare it to your property of values to see if its different. If it is, reload the table and set the property anew, if not, don't.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but this does not really answer my question. I will move the xml parsing to a separate class when I figure this out.

Comment: Please re-read number 2. You're running what you posted every time the view appears. When you navigate away from the view controller and come back the view is appearing and thus running the network call and table reload.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I tried putting the code in viewDidLoad and now the loading screen does not appear